# Overriding an action called from ChildActionExtensions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, action

At the end of my view, I call this:

```
    <%= Html.Action("ProductLayoutAndLimits", this.Model) /* Render product-specific options*/ %>
```

That action is virtual in my controller:

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public virtual ActionResult ProductLayoutAndLimits(DeliveryOptionsViewModel optionsViewModel)
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

The intent was that I would override this method in a product specific controller. So naturally, I did this:

```
    public override System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult ProductLayoutAndLimits(DeliveryOptionsViewModel optionsViewModel)
    {
```

But the breakpoint isn't hitting, so my override is not getting picked up. Is there a different overload I should be using? Or do I need to pass in a different object? Or is there an annotation that I need on my product specific action in order for it to be detected?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit**

While all suggestions are appreciated, I am most interested in solutions that actually answer my question, rather than suggesting a different technique.

Templates have been suggested, but please note that I need controller code to be executed before any new additional view code is rendered. The base controller is in a solution that serves as a platform to other products. They cannot do anything product specific. After they render their view, the intent is that my override of the child action will be called. My controller code will check a number of things in order to determine how to set properties on my model before it renders the view.

**Edit**

I found the problem. I feel silly, as usual. `Html.Action` was being called from Platform's view code. It turned out that we have been using a product specific view for this since July. I didn't notice because we don't typically use product specific views. Whoops!

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in the base controller's ProductLayoutAndLimits method, and is that breakpoint being hit?  If so, you're probably telling Html.Action to use the wrong controller.  If the request originates from Base::SomeAction, then calling Html.Action("SomeOtherAction") will look for Base::SomeOtherAction.  You need to pass "Derived" as a parameter to Html.Action in order to get it to look for Derived::SomeOtherAction.

Comment: See my edit. The call wasn't even being made. Boy do I feel silly :)

Comment: @Levi: Although my problem was actually something that I overlooked, your answer is indeed correct. The only way to hit my product's action would be if my product's controller is the one rendering the view. Would you mind posting this as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using child actions and overriding controllers to handle this? Why not display templates:

```
<%= Html.DisplayForModel("ProductLayoutAndLimits") %>
```

where `ProductLayoutAndLimits` would be the name of the corresponding display template.

Example:

Model:

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public string BaseProp { get; set; }
}

public class DerviedViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string DerivedProp { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new DerviedViewModel
        {
            BaseProp = "base prop",
            DerivedProp = "derived prop"
        });
    }
}
```

View (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
@model AppName.Models.BaseViewModel
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

Display Template (`~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/DerviedViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model AppName.Models.DerviedViewModel
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.BaseProp)
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.DerivedProp)
```

Of course you could also have a display template for the base class (`~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/BaseViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model AppName.Models.BaseViewModel
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.BaseProp)
```

and this template would have been rendered if your controller action had returned the base class as model.

Comment: The reason would be that I can't do anything product specific in the base controller. In other words, I can't set `DerivedProp` from there. The base controller class belongs to code that serves as a platform for other products. It is up to my product specific controller to set values for properties of derived classes.

Comment: @Samo, OK, still the display templates would work great in your case.

Comment: How so? I need controller code in order to set properties. Doing that stuff in the view would break MVC. I don't understand how a template would work for me.

Comment: @Samo, all that you have to write in your view is `<%= Html.DisplayForModel() %>`. There is absolutely nothing wrong about this single line of code in your view that would break the MVC pattern. Then you provide the corresponding display templates as shown in my example. And then based on the type of your model passed to the view, the framework will automatically pick the proper display template.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding me. My controller code needs to make some checks and then explicitly set properties on my model. I can't just tell it to display a template for a certain kind of model and expect it to work.

Comment: @Samo, no I am not understanding what do you have and what you are trying to achieve. Sorry. I hope someone does and would be able to answer your question.